# OWIN Web API with Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have created an OWIN Web API within a Windows Service. The Service is listening on Port 2021 and should be accessible in the Network of my company.

Currently i can access the Service on http://localhost:2021/api/health of my machine. But i'd like to host it also for externel computers. For example my computer name in the network is MyComputerName. In this case i'd like to do http://MyComputerName:2021/api/health . But if i try it i don't get a connection from other clients in this network to my computer.

Is it possible to make a Windows Service which provides a Web Api for other Network participant? In netstat -a i could see that the port is open and there is the "listening".

My Startup - Class looks like the following:

```
 public partial class APIServiceTest : ServiceBase
{
    public string baseAddress = "http://*:2021/";
    private IDisposable _server = null;

    public APIServiceTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if(_server != null)
        {
            _server.Dispose();
        }
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Some ideas? The service is running as a windows service and provides the endpoint at the localhost in a correct way. But the service isn't accessible for other Network Services. Thanks

Comment: It might helpful if you post startup code. Is your endpoint url bind to any(*)? `WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://*:2021")`

Comment: Is your firewall properly setup?